# How to get a long-lived Facebook session?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been working on a Facebook application from last year. It was working good before the Facebook December 2012 changes. But now I'm getting an issue with a Facebook session.
I have replaced the old [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) with the new SDK, [where it is written](https://github.com/kingkarki/facebook-php-sdk/commit/ca9472b3312dab3fdcfbffb4e45eb091f582dcb7):

> Avoid trying to reuse spent authorization codes

So when an authorization code is spent, the user session expires from my site. (I get authorization error after that).

The user gets logout from my application every 5-6 minute, so I have to redirect the user to loginurl  again and page refresh and this is not good for my site, because I'm using an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call on all links.

I have seen some applications which work good after December changes also. (for example, Wrapp.com). Wrapp.com doesn't redirect the user after authentication code expiry. And I can make a post on Facebook without redirect using Wrapp.com after 10 minutes of login too. 
How does Wrapp.com handle authentication? What is the solution?

Comment: NOTE, your tokens should default at 2 hours.  If it is expiring in minutes that means you are not setting accessing token on your ajax page and it is clearing the session.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

1. You can extend the user access token using the scenario 4 tip described in *[Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)*.
2. In my case, I set my application as Desktop, so I have a token that expire in 90 days:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Avoid expiring a session with Ajax and Iframe pages using the PHP SDK.

---

After much research and testing, using PHP SDK "3.2.2" with in an iframe or an Ajax page that is loaded with canvas or page tab, will clear the session for the application if the called page is loaded more than one time.

**EXAMPLE:**

Your page tab loads an iframe inside its self containing PHP SDK, and your user interacts with the iframe. That iframe upon the second page load will clear the current application session.

**SOLUTION:**

Remove PHP SDK from Ajax and iframe pages in your application and use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) instead.

If your iframe page inside your application requires user authentication information, it is suggested to created a cookie or session upon the user landing on the page tab/ canvas or upload the user authentication. Use this switch content where the user is required to view or interact.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shawn for answer. But i have a question here.  I have to get user's friend list on ajax page which requires user access token. How can i get user access token on ajax page where i cannot include facebook sdk?

Comment: Can i store user access token to session and use it while calling api using curl?

Comment: if the access token has been set on your main pages, the ajax page should be able to call it using it's current session.
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppIdHere_access_token'];